# Manually compute a confidence interval for the mean

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I'd like to manually calculate confidence intervals to test a population mean. I chose a sample mean of 1.2, a standard error of 0.05 and tried to calculate the value of the lower limit as follows:

```
Solve[Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], x], {x, -100, y}],  y] == 0.025
(*Solve[0.5 - 0.5 Erf[16.9706 - 14.1421 y], y] == 0.025*)
```

But it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: You can use the`{}` button to neatly format code, or simply indent with four spaces, rather than using `>`

Comment: The correct way to format this code this thus: `Solve[Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], x], {x, -100, y}] ==
   0.025, y]`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the quick answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you don't want to use `CDF[]` or `InverseCDF[]`:

```
Solve[CDF[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], y] == 0.025, y]

InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], 0.025]

Quantile[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], 0.025]
```

but FWIW, your lower limit should be `−∞`: `Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[1.2, .05], x], {x, −∞, y}]`

---

Here's an explicit computation of the CI:

```
With[{c = 0.95, μ = 1.2, σ = 0.05},
     Interval[μ + {-1, 1} σ InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], (1 + c)/2]]]
```

> `Interval[{1.102,1.298}]`

Comment: When I use the lower limit `−∞`, I get an answer that I don't understand:  

`Solve[0.56419 (0.886227 + (
     12.5331 (-1.2 + 1. y) Erf[14.1421 Sqrt[(1.2 - 1. y)^2]])/
     Sqrt[(16.9706 - 14.1421 y)^2]) == 0.025, y]`

Also, I wanted to use Integrate and PDF only to get a clearer view of what was happening; but CDF by itself and the Integrate-PDF couple should produce the same results, right? Thanks for your help, btw

Comment: "I get an answer that I don't understand" - that tells me nothing, since you didn't say which part was not understandable. I presume you're aware of the error function, at the very least?

Comment: Alright, let me explain how much of it I don't understand: I don't know what "Erf" stands for and I don't know how to interpret that output, generally speaking.

Comment: You're dealing with the integral of the Gaussian function; the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) will necessarily pop up. This is not a transcendental function that is usually taught in your high school classes. Anything dealing with integrating the normal distribution comes to this.

Comment: So that's why we had to use the tables instead of just calculating the integral. Then I guess there is no way to use the lower limit `−∞` and still obtain a numerical result?

Comment: Theoretically you can; in practice, `Integrate[]` returns a somewhat inconvenient form that is not usable without further massaging that is too long to get into here. That's why I told you to use `CDF[]` instead.